# What is the best algorithm to calculate the most scored item?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have an music items that are scored by users between 1 to 5, and 
I need a formula to get the 5 most scored items.

But obviously an item that get 3.5 average score from 1000 different users will be more scored then an item thet get 4.9 average score from only 5 users... in other words I think that if an item get attention from people to score it, this indicates that the item is interesting. so in the calculation the votesCount parameter need to have a power. (how much power? I don't sure, and I asking it you to get ideas).

I think that we need the following parameters in the function: votesAverage, votesCount.

Comment: One place to start reading about these types of problems is in the Netflix challenge.  There's a ton of useful and interesting web-posting + algorithm examples dealing with just this sort of thing.

Comment: You need to define this concept of "most scored" better - if you can't, tell us what you hope to achieve with this score; that might give us a better idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: What is wrong with just totaling scores? In your example, one item gets a total of 3,500 and the other only 24.5

Comment: @wheaties Thanks, I'll try to search for it. @Jacob Is it better now? @MAK please try to understand.

Comment: @Carlos Gutiérrez my example its only to make the point. in case that one have 1 average from 1000, and the second have 5 from 150, the second need to win, and t=not the first

Comment: Carlos: an item with 1000 votes of 1 is better than one with 100 votes of 5? :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, despite Mendy liking some answers and not others, every answer (as of 11/3/2010) is exactly the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Weighted voting for 5-star systems with lots of voters

You can use Bayesian estimates to calculate weighted voting.

[IMDb](http://www.imdb.com) (Internet Movie Database) uses this calculation to determine its IMDb Top 250. *(Note: IMDb uses 10 stars but the formulas are identical using 5 stars).*

> The formula for calculating the Top Rated 250 Titles gives a true Bayesian estimate:
>
> weighted rating (WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C
>
> where:
>
> - R = average for the movie (mean) = (Rating)
> - v = number of votes for the movie = (votes)
> - m = minimum votes required to be listed in the Top 250 (currently 3000)
> - C = the mean vote across the whole report (currently 6.9)

[IMDb Reference](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top)

[Wikipedia Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Movie_Database#User_ratings_of_films)

Comment: +1 I'll take a look on it, but what you think, is it good to my case? I have about 35,000 votes, 700 to 1800 per each.

Comment: It sounds like an *ideal* match to me. Try it out with some sample (or real) data and see if the results meet your requirements.

Comment: Just a note for completeness that here WR = (Rv + Cm) / (v+m), which is exactly my solution also (below) when you set H=m

Comment: when m=0 the formula is WR = R = votesAverage. But I said that I want to have the votesCount in the formula too...

Comment: what does the c(the mean vote across the whole report) mean? Can u explain that?

Comment: Can anyone explain what is C in this formula ??

Comment: Using the above formula whenever I set m to anything besides zero all WR values would drop to zero.  The formula provided by @antti-huima works, and is also the formula now listed on the linked wiki page above.

Answer (score 9):

The reddit scoring algorithm is probably the best bet if you really want to do it the right way. It's [explained in detail here](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) and at [a high level by xkcd author Randall here](http://blog.reddit.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html).

The problem is it doesn't really work for five-star ratings which is what you're going for. You should be able to generalize reddit's sorting system to use ratings. Heck, it's probably done somewhere already. I'm going to look for it.

Comment: Since Robert has provided a good example of a five-star rating sorting system (and since I can't find one based on statistical confidence), I'm just going to leave this here. Worst case, you count ratings of 3 and higher as a positive and ratings of 2 and lower as a negative and use those results as your inputs to the Wilson score interval.

Comment: The point of the reddit algo is to find a lower bound 90% confidence interval on the actual rating. It ought to be fairly easy to generalise this from yes/no ratings to a 5 star system.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to balance the system is to add a fixed number of hypothetical users (say the count is H) who all vote for the long-term average A of all your pieces. Say that average is 3; then the formula becomes

Score = (votesCount x votesAverage + H x A) / (votesCount + H)

Now when votesCount grows, the relative impact of the hypothetical average-voters diminishes.

You can set H experimentally, or by thinking about it. E.g. if you think that 20 votes is sufficient to establish relatively strong rating, you could set H=5. Say.

Comment: +1 For very interesting answer. I don't think it good to my case, because I don't need to show rating, what I need to do is to get the 5 that need to win.

Comment: Well you can sort according to this modified score and show the 5 highest

Answer (score 0):

I am using for my music files following method:

Rating is measured in percents (0-100)
Songs which are not rated get 50% as a gift
Every time someone votes for a song its rating is incremented
Every time someone votes against the song its rating is decremented
If song rating goes higher than MAX which is 100, then MAX is set to current song rating
If song rating goes below MIN, then MIN is set to song rating
After every voting which changes MIN or MAX I am doing normalization for every song in the list like that:

NewRating = (CurrentRating - MIN) *100/(MAX -MIN) Then I am setting back MIN to 0, and MAX to 100.

This method gives equal chance for old and new songs to get the right rating quickly. Also each vote on best and worst song effects others, what I also consider as right thing to do.

When choosing songs to play (or to vote) I am generating a random number in range of 0-100 and searching for the next song with rating equal or higher than this number.

Bad songs are going down and chosen rarely, good songs are going up and are chosen more frequently but I am still leaving a chance for even worst song to be played(voted) sometime in the future.

Answer (score -1):

The term for this is [bayesian estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator).

One common example:

> Bayesian rating = `(v*R + m*C)/(v+m)`
>   where:
>   **R** = average rating of song
>   **v** = number of votes for the song
>   **m** = minimum votes required to be listed (ex. 10)
>   **C** = average vote across *all* songs

Comment: But when `m=0` => `Bayesian rating = R`. And I looking to keep `v` in the function.

Comment: @Mendy... so don't set m to 0.  The whole point is that you want to list the top-10 rated songs; a song with only 5 or 6 votes does not have enough votes to decide (statistically) if it is better or worse than a song with 1000 votes, even if the second one has an average of 3.0 stars and the first has all 5's