# using Bayesian algorithm to calculate the top 10 products

Tags: c#, algorithm, average, bayesian

So in my system which is written in c#, the user can rate the product from 1 to 5 with the chunks of 0.5 points, so basically the points are **0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0** now I want to calculate the top products, and lets say the minimum numbers of votes needed is 10 votes. I have to 2 sample products with the information as below:

```
product 1 {

    total rating: 360.5,
    number of votes: 212
}

product 2 { 
    total rating: 28.0,
    number of votes: 12
}
```

so basically the average rating for each product is

```
product 1 -> 360.5 / 212 = 1.70

product 2 -> 28.0 / 12 = 2.33
```

now following the formula mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134504/what-is-the-best-algorithm-to-calculate-the-most-scored-item)

```
weighted rating (WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C

where:

R = average for the movie (mean) = (Rating)
v = number of votes for the movie = (votes)
m = minimum votes required to be listed in the Top 50 (currently 20)
C = the mean vote across the whole report (currently 2.01)
```

formula for product 1 is:

```
(212 / (212 + 20)) * 1.70 + (20 / (212 + 20)) * 2.01 = 1.72
```

and for product 2 is:

```
(12 / (12 + 20)) * 2.33 + (20 / (12 + 20)) * 2.01 = 2.13
```

First of all I wanna know if my calculation is correct and if it is then basically a product with 200 more votes and difference of 0.42 points is still lower than a product with 12 votes ? Doesn't those 200 more votes make the product 1 more favorite than product 1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A product with 212 votes vs a product with 12 votes doesn't necessarily mean the one with 212 votes is the favorite.  It could just mean it's been up longer.  E.g. say the product with 212 votes was posted on jan 1, 2013, and the product with 12 votes was posted yesterday.  Short version is that more votes doesn't mean favoritism.  

With rating systems with sort by rating systems, users will sort products by best rating or most ratings, and fall for buying that product, farther alienating lower rated products from higher ones.

You can't reliably use rating count as a measure of favortism.

Comment: @Ryios Thanks for the clarification and I see your point, but what if both products are created at the same day? Is there any way to consider the creation date of products into this algorithm?

Comment: @arashmoeen If you know the date each rating is cast you can weight each vote based on its age.  See the algorithms for, say, calculating the score of a Reddit post; they incorporate the age of each vote (making it worth less and less over time) when determining the real score of each post.  You wouldn't be able to use something like that exactly, but it should give you a starting place.